# SPARK - ERROR ShutdownHookManager: Exception while deleting Spark temp dir

Tags: python, windows, apache-spark, pyspark

I tried to execute the next code:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
import pandas as pd
import urllib3
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.ml.regression import LinearRegression
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler


spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('sparkdf').getOrCreate() #creamos session Spark
```

But I get the following error:

```
23/08/29 15:05:06 WARN Shell: Did not find winutils.exe: java.io.FileNotFoundException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: HADOOP_HOME and hadoop.home.dir are unset. -see         https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WindowsProblems
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
23/08/29 15:05:07 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
23/08/29 15:05:09 ERROR ShutdownHookManager: Exception while deleting Spark temp dir:     C:\Users\cti5360\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-15d7079b-6cf6-45ae-9e59-c44f94f6d849\pyspark-78ddb6cb-dbc6-4d42-bbf7-e7677967a7a8

java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Users\cti5360\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-15d7079b-6cf6-45ae-    9e59-c44f94f6d849\pyspark-78ddb6cb-dbc6-4d42-bbf7-e7677967a7a8
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(Unknown Source)
at java.nio.file.Files.readAttributes(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.network.util.JavaUtils.deleteRecursivelyUsingJavaIO(JavaUtils.java:128)
at org.apache.spark.network.util.JavaUtils.deleteRecursively(JavaUtils.java:121)
at org.apache.spark.network.util.JavaUtils.deleteRecursively(JavaUtils.java:94)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.deleteRecursively(Utils.scala:1231)
at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.$anonfun$new$4(ShutdownHookManager.scala:65)
at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.$anonfun$new$4$adapted(ShutdownHookManager.scala:62)
at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:36)
at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach$(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:198)
at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.$anonfun$new$2(ShutdownHookManager.scala:62)
at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHook.run(ShutdownHookManager.scala:214)
at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.$anonfun$runAll$2(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:2088)
at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.$anonfun$runAll$1(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.runAll(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anon$2.run(ShutdownHookManager.scala:178)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
CORRECTO: el proceso con PID 12868 (proceso secundario de PID 26036)
ha sido terminado.
CORRECTO: el proceso con PID 26036 (proceso secundario de PID 16300)
ha sido terminado.
CORRECTO: el proceso con PID 16300 (proceso secundario de PID 12920)
ha sido terminado.
```

Thanks for the answers
I have to write something because the stack overflow said me that "the post is mostly code please add some more details" and y i have to write that last line

Comment: Does the path `C:\Users\cti5360\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-15d7079b-6cf6-45ae-9e59-c44f94f6d849\pyspark-78ddb6cb-dbc6-4d42-bbf7-e7677967a7a8` exits? If not, try creating it. Other thing you can try is setting `spark.local.dir` to other path.